# Builder with optional source

Tags: scons

I want to make a Builder with one or more optional sources.

I tried this:

```
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'my_builder': Builder(action = Action(do_something))})

def do_something(target, source, env):
    if source[1]:
        do_optional_stuff(source[1])
    do_other_stuff(target, source[0])

...

env.my_builder(target.txt, [source1, None])    # Fails
env.my_builder(target.txt, [source2, source3]) # Okay
```

The trouble is, I get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_ninfo'` when I pass in None, because scons is expecting `Node` arguments, and None isn't acceptable.

Is there anything I can do?

**Edit:**

As noted in the answer below, it's possible to solve this for the simple case of one optional argument, by varying the length of source list.  This doesn't work for making arbitrary arguments optional, so I'd still be interested in a way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding a bogus element, check the length of the *source* list (or better yet, iterate over the list starting after the first element):

```
def do_something(target, source, env):
    if len(source) > 1:
        do_optional_stuff(source[1])
    # or:
    # for opt_src in source[1:]:
    #   do_optional_stuff(opt_src)
    do_main_stuff(target, source[0])

env.Append(BUILDERS = {'my_builder': Builder(action = Action(do_something))})

env.my_builder('target-2.txt', ['foo.txt'])
env.my_builder('target-1.txt', ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt'])
```

One issue with this approach is that you need to ensure that your sources are listed in the right order. Depending on the details of what you're doing, you might be able to filter the *source* list by matching file names or extensions. After all, this is Python code, you have the full power of the language at your disposal.

Comment: These are good suggestions for the question as asked :-).  Unfortunately I simplified the question, and they won't work for my real situation.  I have multiple optional sources, all with the same file extension, so there's no way to tell what's missing if I just vary the number of sources passed in.  For that situation, I think I might need to make multiple builders which accept different source lists.